# Instance of reactJs component to render a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can I use an instance of a reactJS component to render a component. 
Eg, Let's say my reactJS component is

```
class myComponent extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      next:false
    }
    this.alertSomething = this.alertSomething.bind(this);
    this.showNext = this.showNext.bind(this);
  }

  showNext(){
    console.log('wow');
    console.log(this.state, this, this.state.next);
    this.setState({next:true});
  }

  alertSomething(){
    alert('Alert Something')
    console.log(this.state, this, this.state.next);
    this.setState({next:true});
  }

  render(){

    return(
      <div className='column'>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default myComponent
```

Now, inside my another component can I do;

```
    let x = new displayContent.renderComponent();
    render(
     <x />
     //or
     <x.render />
    )
```

// I tried both it didn't work, I thought there mush be some other way to achieve this, after all every component is just a javascript object.

Also at the same time, can I  call  function to make change in its state. Like.

```
x.someFunction();
```

where `someFunctino` is inside that react component, doing `setState`.

Is it possible? OR am I missing something?

Edit: I clearly understand that when you want to render a react component, you can always do, `<component />`.
This question is just out of curiosity, can this be done? if not, then why?, I mean how is that different from other javascript objects.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You can just do `<myComponent />`, why isn't that what you're asking?

Comment: Hi, @DaveNewton, there is not a doubt that I should use <myComponent />. However, i just wanted to know if creating a instance of a component and then rendering, what would it do? i wanted to know where exactly the instance creation takes place. After all every component is just a class. And is there any way we can create an instance explicitly.

Comment: It's just a class, so you can create an instance wherever you want.

Comment: component names cannot start with `lowercase` letter - `JSX` requirement

Comment: `ReactDOM.render` takes instance of component and mount it to location in `DOM` provided for eg. `ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.body)`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use the `React.createElement` method to render a component:

```
React.createElement(Component, params)
```

but with JSX, this is the same:

```
<Component />
```

Refer to [Multiple components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html) in the React documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you're supposed to use React. You don't have to handle object instantiations ; React do this for you. Use composition instead.

```
render() {
  return (
    <myComponent />
  )
}
```

Also, if you want to set the state of a child component from a parent component, you should probably move the logic in the parent.

Comment: You mean, all this instantiation is done inside react implicitly every time we use that component?

Comment: Yes. You can read this to have a better understanding of React [https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for something like this.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import CamCapture from './CamCapture.js';

export default class ProctorVideoFeed extends Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.Camera = React.createElement(CamCapture);
    
    }

    //this.handleVideoClick = this.handleVideoClick.bind(this);


render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <span>{this.Camera}</span>
            <button onClick = {this.Camera.StopRecording}>Stop</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Here StopRecording is a function defined inside CamCapture class.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can format code